# How to store an API token on a node server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, shopify

I understand that a client obtaining a token from my service will just get put into a cookie, or session storage, but if I obtain an API token from a service like Shopify, how should I store it on the server?

I was thinking of just creating a model in Mongodb and storing it in a collection. Is it safe to store an obtained token in a database? Moreover, should I encrypt it in any way before I save it to the database?

Comment: Yes it is. If your db gets breached, you can simply invalidate all tokens. If someone really breaks your server, encryption wouldnt help either

Comment: Great. And to invalidate all tokens, I'd change the secret on the server end?

Comment: Actually I don't understand this. Invalidating all tokens for users of my app makes sense (I'd just change the secret). But if my database gets breached and they get the token for the third party API service, I don't have any control over the invalidation of the token... the third party service does. So how would I invalidate a token there?

Comment: You would invalidate your DB tokens from inside Shopify. Your partner dashboard access to your App comes with a reset button. So carry on. Worry not about losing control of your MongoDB. That would be major embarrassing but not end of the world right.